# How does copying an array with array2=("${array1[@]}") differ from direct assignment?

Tags: bash

Consider the following mechanism of copying content from one array to another:

```
$ array1=( [1]=a [2]=b [5]=c )
$ array2=( "${array1[@]}" )
```

One known side effect of this is that the indices will not be preserved, which can be demonstrated as follows:

```
# note that indices have changed from 1/2/5 to 0/1/2
$ declare -p array1 array2
declare -a array1='([1]="a" [2]="b" [5]="c")'
declare -a array2='([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")'
```

Are there any other side effects of using this syntax, or places where its effect differs from directly assigning `array2=( [1]=a [2]=b [5]=c )`?

Comment: It may be a disadvantage for you, but actually it's not.

Comment: Disavantage compared to what ? You cannot give advantages or disadvantages when you compare something to .

Comment: @user84 Welcome to [so]! The advantages or disadvantages of one method over another will vary depending on your *goal*, which will vary from one task to another. (If one option were always better, then both would not be included in the language.) Using neutral language to discuss the question allows answers to remain objective, while still giving you the same information.

Answer (score 0):

The difference you named -- discarding indices -- is the *only* difference in effect (discarding performance implications, which are version-dependent and difficult to measure). That said, there is at least one further issue that falls out from this: The syntax in question is unable to copy associative, vs numerically indexed, arrays.

The terseness, clarity and safety of this syntax (as opposed to hackery such as using `eval`) is generally considered sufficient advantage to make it appropriate for general use in situations where preserving indices is unimportant.